# How can i use session from yii framework into my 3rd party application

Tags: php, yii

I use **Yii framework** and in the framework i use 3rd party application which is **mibew Messenger** (or chat ).

What I need is to pass `$_session` variable (username and password) from yii framework to **Mibew messenger**, I need this because I want to be log in automatically when I log in into my yii application.

**Mibew messenger** folder is in the app folder of the application.

So how can I use the same session outside of **yii framework** ?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you may do following:

1) In file of 3rd party application where you need to get an access to SESSION:

> ```
> require('/path/to/framework/YiiBase.php');
> ```

2) If you have specific configs for sessions, than you need you configs:

> ```
> $config = require('/path/to/protected/config/main.php');
> $session = YiiBase::createComponent($config['components']['session']);
> ```

3) For standard sessions (instead step #2) you should try:

> ```
> $session = new CHttpSession();
> ```

Than you can work with sessions as in framework: `$session[$var_name]` or `$session->get/set($var_name)`.

I don't check it solution. If there will be an error - write it on comments.

**UPDATED**

Just need to do:

> ```
> require('/path/to/framework/YiiBase.php');
> $config = require('/path/to/configs_directory/main.php');
> Yii::createWebApplication($config);
> ```

Than you can use all framework features by `Yii::app()`

Comment: thank you for your answer, do you know what should i do if i need to use 'Yii::app()->user' how to get it? do i need to include any other file ? Thanks

Comment: Yes, you need create an object of CWebUser. It object get all information from session itself. Wait a second. New solution (if it correct I'm rewrite my answer): try include `YiiBase.php` and your configs. The do `Yii::createWebApplication($config)` (as in `index.php` without calling method `run()`). Then, I think, you may using `Yii::app()` in your 3rd app. It must working!

Comment: ok, i put 

require('../../framework/YiiBase.php');
require('../../protected/config/main.php');

Yii::createWebApplication($config);

and i got error, fatal one :) **( ! ) Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class YiiBase in /opt/local/www/projects/theuniversalgroup/app/framework/YiiBase.php on line 55**

Comment: sorry my mistake, i add some code and now it's ok :) i forgot to add $config is equal to :)
like this : 
require('../../framework/yii.php');
$config = require('../../protected/config/main.php');

Yii::createWebApplication($config);

Answer (score 1):

You can get the logged in user ID by `Yii::app()->user->id;` then query the username and password at your database using the logged in id as follows:

```
$userInfo = User::model()->findByPk(array('id'=>Yii::app()->user->id));
$user = $userInfo->username;
$password = md5($this->userInfo->password);
```

Now you can put these variables into session what I do not think is necessary. Because you should put these variables to the **mibew** directly. However if you would like to put these variable into the Yii session just do this following:

```
Yii::app()->session['usename']  = $user;
Yii::app()->session['password'] = $password;
```

This is details just make for your own.

Answer (score 1):

**For Yii2 it is done like this:**

```php
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);  //set these according to your needs
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php');
require(__DIR__ . '/../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');

$config = require(__DIR__ . '/../config/web.php');

new yii\web\Application($config);
```

Then you'll probably want to immediately open the session so that $_SESSION will always be available hereafter:

```
Yii::$app->session->open();
```

You can now use either `$_SESSION` like normal, or you can use eg. `Yii::$app->session['sessionvarname'] = 'somevalue';` (or any method described in the guide chapter [Session and Cookies](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-sessions-cookies.html)).

Also, if for example you wanted to use some of the assets from Yii you could load them like this:

```
$asset = Yii::$app->assetManager->getBundle('yii\web\YiiAsset', true);
echo yii\helpers\Html::jsFile(Yii::$app->assetManager->getAssetUrl($asset, 'yii.js'));
// -- or --
echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="'. Yii::$app->assetManager->getAssetUrl($asset, 'yii.js') .'"></script>';
```